# Yahoo, Google, Yelp API

Tags: yahoo, yelp

Is there any php API to gather information about a business(address, reviews) by its phone number from Yelp, Google, Insiderpages, Yahoo..
Please help, i have done research about these, but did't get the right info, though yelp is providing info by it's phone number but there they ask ywsid as mendatory (http://api.yelp.com/phone_search?phone=1234567890&ywsid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) but i want by phone number only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that all APIs have terms, most of them won't allow you to store their data in your own database and most of them have display requirements, before proceeding with any developing please read carefully their display requirements and terms.

Depending on your project you might not be allowed to use the data as you might need/want to on your project.

The other alternative would be scrapping sites, but most sites have rules against scraping too...

And again **read a lot** before putting too effort on something you are prohibited to in first place.

**Yelp**

ywsid = API key, you need to get your own key if you are using the yelp API, [get it here](http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started/api_access)

 if you are using it to add it to your own database or storing the information anywhere it is against their policies [display requirements](http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started/display_requirements) & [api terms](http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started/api_terms).

if you are using any API you must read their terms before even thinking of doing anything.

**Google Places**

[API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)

**Insiderpages**

I Don't think they have one but you could use the [citygrid API](http://docs.citygridmedia.com/display/citygridv2/CityGrid+APIs) that does a [lot of sites] search at once.

**Yahoo**

[Yahoo API](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/local/V3/localSearch.html)

**CityGrid**

As mentioned before [citygrid API](http://docs.citygridmedia.com/display/citygridv2/CityGrid+APIs)

**Foursquare**

[Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/)

**Merchant Circle**

[Merchant Circle API](http://api.merchantcircle.com/api/v1/docs)

**White Pages**

[White Pages API](http://developer.whitepages.com/)

**Yellow Pages**

[Yellow Pages API](http://developer.yp.com/apis)

Bottom line is, all these companies have put a lot of time and effort and  **money** to build their databases, and they want you to redirect people back to their pages so they can make their money back/profit.